# ABP.IO GetAsync among all Tenants

Tags: entity-framework-core, abp

ABP adds an additional Tenant filter for entities that implement IMultiTenant interface.
So when we use a standard repository the filter will be applied:

```
public class OrderService : ApplicationService, IOrderService, ITransientDependency
{
    public IReadOnlyRepository<Order, Guid> _repository { get; set; }

    public async Task<OrderDto> GetAsync(Guid id)
    {
        Order order = await _repository.FindAsync(id); //Is it possible to search among all tenants?
        return ObjectMapper.Map<Order, OrderDto>(order);
    }
}
```

Looking at the query it produces, it looks like there has to be a way to avoid this filter, maybe through an additional parameter or smth like this.

```
SELECT TOP(2) *
FROM [AbpOrders] AS [a]
WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_0 = CAST(1 AS bit) OR [a].[TenantId] IS NULL) AND ([a].Id = @__Id_0)
```

if we somehow pass '@__ef_filter__p_0' parameter then it will search among all tenants.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you do that
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Data-Filtering#idatafilter-service-enable-disable-data-filters

```
public class OrderService : ApplicationService, IOrderService, ITransientDependency
{
    public IDataFilter DataFilter { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyRepository<Order, Guid> Repository { get; set; }

    public async Task<OrderDto> GetAsync(Guid id)
    {
        //Temporary disable the IMultiTenant filter
        using (DataFilter.Disable<Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy.IMultiTenant>())
        {
            Order order = await Repository.FindAsync(id);
            return ObjectMapper.Map<Order, OrderDto>(order);
        }
    }
}
```